# Criteria on expression

Tags: database, ms-access

OK, so I'm working in MS Access and have a pretty complicated expression (it takes the values of other fields into consideration and outputs a value accordingly using `IIf` logic). I want to *not* include some of the values in my final query output.

Without posting the exact and entire `IIf` statement, it's something like this example:

`If field1=1 and field2>=field3 and field4=N` then Yes, else No (it's way more complicated than that but you get the idea...

and let's say I want to *not* include the Yes results.

Access won't let me put criteria for an expression field. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It has been a long while since I used Access - like back when smoke signals were a modern means of communicating long distances.

With that being said, I would take the approach of breaking the problem down into smaller subsets.  Focus first on getting the data set you want, then returning the fields you need and any other possible filtering.  In Access you should be able to base a query on a query if memory serves.

Do something like this:

**Query 1**: contains your complicated formula with ALL required fields

**Query 2**: uses query 2 as its source, limiting the fields returned and possibly additional filtering.

```
select field1,field3,field4
from (
        select field1,field2,field3, iif(field1 .....
        from myTable
      )
```